# Laravel - Popular uma lista com arquivos em um diretório

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Gostaria de popular uma lista numa página Blade, no Framework Laravel. Tentei fazer

```
<select id="idSelMinhaLista">
    @if(isset($arrayRemessa))
        @for($i=0;$i < count($arrayRemessa);$i++)
            <option>{{$arrayRemessa[$i]}}</option>
        @endfor
    @endif
</select>
```

A variável $arrayRemessa é alimentada por uma chamada a um método PHP, que, por sua vez, faz um Return chamando a View Blade que mostra a select acima. O método faz:

```
public function listarArquivosRemessa(){

    $arrayRemessa = [];
    $filesInFolder = \File::files('assets/remessa');

    foreach($filesInFolder as $path)
    {
        $arrayRemessa[] = pathinfo($path);
    }
    return view ("PesquisaView")->with("arrayRemessa",$arrayRemessa);
}//listarArquivosRemessa
```

Meu problema é que tenho o erro abaixo:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

---

A minha saída 'covarde' foi usar jQuery. Isto é:

Na View, simplesmente:

```
<select id="idSelItauArquivosRemessa">
</select>
<button type="button" id="idBtnRefreshListaRemessaItau">Refresh</button>
```

No jQuery:

```
jQuery("#idBtnRefreshListaRemessa").click(function (){
    var objSel=jQuery("#idSelItauArquivosRemessa");
    objSel.empty();
    var concatena='<option value="0" title="0"></option>';
        jQuery.get("itauRefreshArquivosRemessa",function(retorno){
            for(i=0;i < retorno.length;i++){
                concatena=concatena+'<option value="'+retorno[i].basename+' "title="'+retorno[i].basename+'">'+retorno[i].basename+'</option>';
            }//for
         objSel.append(concatena);
        });//get
});//idBtnRefreshListaRemessa
```

Na Route:
  Route::get('itauRefreshArquivosRemessa','DespesasController@listarArquivosRemessaItau');

No método:

```
public function listarArquivosRemessaItau(){
    $arrayRemessa = array_map('pathinfo', \File::files('assets/remessa'));
    return $arrayRemessa;
}//listarArquivosRemessaItau
```

Comment: De onde saiu essa classe `File`?

Comment: Você pode melhorar o seu código mais ainda fazendo simplesmente `$arrayRemessa = array_map('pathinfo', \File::file('assets/remessa'))`. Não é necessário fazer todas essas operações, quando se usa funções que simplificam o trabalho

Comment: Além do mais, seria melhor usar `foreach` ao invés de `for`

Comment: não deu certo para mim nenhuma dessas abordagens, mas resolvi via jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

Isso é porque ao colocar algo entre **`{{ }}`**, o Laravel vai tentar fazer um escape do que estiver ali e só possível escapar *strings*.

Neste caso, o conteúdo de `$arrayRemessa[$i]` é um *array* e por isso está estourando este erro.

Entenda que o retorno de `path_info` é um *array* associativo, ou seja, **cada posição em `$arrayRemessa`** contém um array associativo com os dados daquela pasta.

As *keys* deste *array* são **`dirname`**, **`basename`**, **`extension`** e **`filename`**.

Você vai precisar escolher qual deles deseja mostrar na *view*, por exemplo:

```
@for($i=0;$i < count($arrayRemessa);$i++)
    <option>{{ $arrayRemessa[$i]['filename'] }}</option>
@endfor
```

Além disso, o código pode ficar um pouco melhor:

```
public function listarArquivosRemessa()
{    
    $arrayRemessa = array_map('pathinfo', \File::files('assets/remessa'));
    $arrayView = array_pluck($arrayRemessa, 'dirname');
    // (^) Isso vai extrair apenas as keys que você precisa

    return view ("PesquisaView")->with("arrayRemessa", $arrayView);
}
```

E na *view* pode ficar assim:

```
@foreach($arrayRemessa as $item)
    <option>{{ $item }}</option>
@endfor
```

Comment: Usei seu código, mas a select na View não é populada. Fica em branco, embora a resposta do método em PHP tenha capturado valores. Vou fazer outra abordagem, de modo que o retorno do método que gera o array simples, preenche o select via jQuery.

Comment: @MauroSimoes Mas o que foi passado para a view é um array simples. Qual o problema com a abordagem da minha resposta?

Comment: Para lhe ser franco, não consegui reproduzir. Inspecionei o que saía do método e estava populado, mas, na View, usando quaisquer das duas sugestões (com <option>{{item}}</option> e a outra com <option>{{ $arrayRemessa[$i]['filename'] }}</option>) não mostrou. Devo ter cometido algum erro não-evidente. Te agradeço muito.

Comment: @MauroSimoes Se você fizer um `dd($arrayView);`, qual é a saída?

Comment: Sai o seguinte: array:5 [  0 => array:4 [    "dirname" => "assets/remessa"    "basename" => "163RC.XLS"    "extension" => "XLS"    "filename" => "163RC"  ]  1 => array:4 [    "dirname" => "assets/remessa"    "basename" => "163remessa.txt"    "extension" => "txt"    "filename" => "163remessa"  ]  2 => array:4 [    "dirname" => "assets/remessa"    "basename" => "229RC.COB"    ....

Comment: Mas, isto com a seguinte instrução, antes: $arrayRemessa = array_map('pathinfo', \File::files('assets/remessa')); (Não usei o pluck)

Comment: @MauroSimoes Você tem que usar o pluck, ou então especificar a _key_ na view '-'

Comment: Eu usei também, mas não rolou.